# replace empty strings in a dataframe with values from another dataframe iwth a different index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

two sample dataframes with ***different index values***, but identical column names and order:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, '', 3], ['', 2, '']], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[2,4])
```

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, '', 3], ['', 2, '']], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[7,9])
df1

```
    A   B   C
2   1       3
4       2
```

df2

```
   A    B   C
7       4   
9   5       6
```

I know how to concat the two dataframes, but that gives this:

```
   A    B   C
2   1       3
4       2
```

Omitting the non=matching indexes from the other df

result I am trying to achieve is:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   4   3   
1   5   2   6
```

I want to combine the rows with the same index values from each df so that missing values in one df are replaced by the corresponding value in the other.

Concat and Merge are not up to the job I have found.
I assume I have to have identical indexes in each df which correspond to the values I want to merge into one row.  But, so far, no luck getting it to come out correctly.  Any pandas transformational wisdom is appreciated.

This merge attempt did not do the trick:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='outer')
```

The solutions below were all offered before I edited the question. My fault there, I neglected to point out that my actual data has different indexes in the two dataframes.

Comment: your are not trying to concatenate then, but to merge according to an index. The result should not have both index 0 but the second index should be 1

Comment: This merge didn't do the trick however.  df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='outer')

Comment: @timgeb  Yes, I edited the question.  Good catch.  I mistakenly transposed those numbers.

Comment: Also why is the index of the result `0 0` not `0 1`?

Comment: And @timgeb that answer worked perfectly.  Trying it on the actual larger dataset now.

Comment: that 0 0 index for the expected result, also a typo.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df1.shape[1]):
        if df1.iloc[i,j]=="":
            df1.iloc[i,j] = df2.iloc[i,j]

print(df1)


    A   B   C
0   1   4   3
1   5   2   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `mask`

```
out = df1.mask(df1=='',df2)
Out[428]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  4  3
1  5  2  6
```

Comment: I realized that my actual dataset are two dataframes with  the same column names, but different index values.  How could this mask work using a column name (appearing in both dataframes) to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Since the index of your two dataframes are different, it's easier to make it into the same index.

```
index = [i for i in range(len(df1))]
df1.index = index
df2.index = index

ddf = df1.replace('',np.nan)).fillna(df2)
```

If both df1 and df2 have different size of datas, it's still workable.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, '', 3], ['', 2, ''],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'],index=[7,8,9,10])

index1 = [i for i in range(len(df1))]
index2 = [i for i in range(len(df2))]
df1.index = index1
df2.index = index2
df1.replace('',np.nan).fillna(df2)
```

You can get

```
Out[17]: 
      A     B     C
0   1.0     5   3.0
1     4   2.0     6
2   7.0   8.0   9.0
3  10.0  11.0  12.0
```

Comment: I realized that my actual dataset are two dataframes with  the same column names, but different index values.  How could this solution work using a column name (appearing in both dataframes) to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is this helpful for you?

Comment: Thank you for taking another look at my poorly worded question.  My actual data is unique individuals  who have records in both datasets.  So, if I just change the indexes on both, it could mix records from different individuals on the same row.  So, my data is in random order, but the same people in both datasets.  I think I have to make one of the columns, one that identifies that row, an index then use your approach.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes you can go ahead and try it out. But of course, both the datasets must have same size for the index to work

Comment: Ah, well that is an additional issue then.  My two dataframes will always be, df1 = 25 records (for example), df2 = 20 records (for example).  My goal is to blend those two, where the indexes are the same, use df2 values to replace missing data from the corresponding index values in df1 but then add the additional records from df1 to the overall dataset.  Quite complex.

Comment: In that case, it's still possible. I have edited the answer